# How to create a csv file from an existing csv file?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a csv file with about 50000 rows, I want to create another csv file with selective datasets from the csv file. How should I do it?

Comment: Open the file, filter it according to your selection criteria and safe the resulting dataset. Alas, with no code shown, or other details, it's impossible to say more than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try the pandas library, it's the most intuitive to start manipulating data on python:

First load your data :

```
       path_to_file = "file.csv"
       df =  pd.read_csv(path_to_file)
```

then apply a filter on your data,  for example if you only want the first two columns :

```
       df2 = df.iloc[:,[0,1]]
```

Then save your data in a new csv file:

```
       df2.to_csv('file2.csv')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. But if I want to do it with the columns what code should I write?

Comment: Thanks got it finally! :)